# Transit through Gatwick - Filipino

Tags: visas, uk, transit, paperwork, filipino-citizens

I am flying Norwegian Air from Orlando, FL, to Singapore via Gatwick.  There is a change of plane on Norwegian but the bag is checked through. I'm not leaving the airport. Do I need a transit visa? Filipino passport holder leaving work and I have a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the GOV.UK website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/transit/somewhere_else/no), Filipino citizens don't require an airside Transit visa.

So no